# How to access a variable from different functions of the same class?

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, variables, global-variables

Controller:

```
function act() {
    //some code for connection
    $input = (response from client);
    return $input;
}
```

This is the first time the act will be called so as to connect to the client.
Here I'll get the input variable with connection.

```
function a() {
    $a = $this->act();  
}
```

How would I get the `$input` in this function without making the connections again?

```
function b() {

}
```

I have tried putting it the session flashdata but it's not working.

Comment: why dont you just do the same thing with what you did in `function a()` ?

Comment: Because that would presumably make the connections again, which he said he wants to avoid?

Comment: then that means he needs to pass the `$input` through `parameters`

Comment: can you elaborate please.. pass it as parameter in the sense in the fuction call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple in your `class` define a variable like

```
 in controller class below function is written. 
Class myclass {
public  $_customvariable;

function act(){
   //some code for connection
 $this->_customvariable=  $input = (response from client);
   return $input;
}

function a() {
$a = $this->act();  
}
function b(){
 echo $this->_customvariable;//contains the $input value 
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

In order to get to that variable, you'd need to put it outside of the function itself.

```
class MyController extends CI_Controller
{
    private $variable;

    private function act()
    {
        $input = (response from client)
        return $input
    }

    private function a()
    {
        $this->variable = $this->act();
    }
}
```

Doing that will make you able to access the variable from everywhere within the class.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
class fooBar {

    private $connection;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->act();
    }

    public function act(){
       //some code for connection
       $this->connection = (response from client);
    }

    public function a() {
        doSomething($this->connection);
    }

    public function b() {
        doSomething($this->connection);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use statics variables inside methods or functions, the response is kind of "cached" in the function

```
function act(){
    static $input;
    if (empty($input))
    {
        //some code for connection
        $input = (response from client);
    }
    return $input;
}
```